# SQL to DAX with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, dax

How would one translate the following SQL query into DAX:

```
WITH SensorTimes As (
   SELECT sensorID, MAX(timestamp) "LastReading"
   FROM sensorTable
   GROUP BY sensorID
)
SELECT s.sensorID,s.timestamp,s.sensorField1,s.sensorField2 
FROM sensorTable s
INNER JOIN SensorTimes t on s.sensorID = t.sensorID and s.timestamp = t.LastReading
```

The context
I need to retrieve the latest values collected by every sensors so:

1. I get the latest timestamp for each sensor
2. I join on my sensorTable with the timestamp calculated earlier

Comment: If you are in Excel or Power BI, this would be more easily handled in with Power Query rather than DAX. What is the context you are working in?

Comment: Power BI, but I need to dynamically adjust the values retrieved based on the dates chosen by the user in the report

Comment: Which values in your SQL query above are supposed to be dynamic?

Comment: The user will choose a range of dates, one of the info to visualize is the latest state of the sensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would approach this.

1. Create a calendar DateTable (you can use `CALENDAR` or `CALENDARAUTO`) to bridge your two tables.
2. Relate the tables on their TimeStamp columns like so:
   [image: DateTable]
3. You can create a slicer on your DateTable to filter your date range.
4. Create a matrix with `SensorID` in the Rows field.
5. Create a `LastReading` measure and put it in the Values field.

---

```
LastReading = MAX(SensorTable[TimeStamp])
```

---

6. Create any needed `SensorField` measures. For example,

---

```
Field1 = 
    VAR LastReading = [LastReading]
    RETURN CALCULATE(MAX(SensorTable[SensorField1]),
               SensorTimes[TimeStamp] = LastReading)
```

---

**Note**: You may need to create a date column related to the `TimeStamp` to bridge the tables properly. (Create the relationship on the `DateStamp` instead.)

```
DateStamp = DATEVALUE(SensorTable[TimeStamp])
```